# Get records with specific attribute value and has id in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Ruby on Rails 3, I am trying to store a variable with records that have the attribute :attend value of "Yes" but that also have a user_id that belongs to one reseller_id.

A Reseller has many User. A Certificate belongs to one User. I can get the variable to store the Users and/or Resellers based on the :user_id attribute in Certificate but cannot figure out to get it to store based on the Certificate attribute value as "Yes" or "No"

Controller defining variables:

```
@certs = Certificate.all
    @reseller_users_incerts = []  
    @trained_user_id = []
    @certs.each do |user|
      #if user.find_by_attend("Yes")
        @trained_user_id << user.user_id #all user ids in certification table
        id = user.user_id                 
        if u = User.find(id)
        @reseller_users_incerts << u.reseller_id  #all reseller ids from certifications table
      end
      #end
    end
```

The @reseller_users_incerts gives me the ids of all resellers with users that have certificate records saved. I need to also store variables based on the Certificate :attend value of "Yes" or "No"

This is the view:

```
<% if @reseller_users_incerts.include?(reseller.id) %>
    <td><%= "Yes" %></td>
<% else %>
    <td><%= "No" %></td>
<% end %>
```

Certificate model:

```
class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :attend, :pass, :user_id

belongs_to :user

validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner block is confusing because you're using `user` as a loop variable when it's really a `Certificate`. Changing that variable and assuming that `attend` is indeed an attribute of `Certificate`, then introducing this check using your existing structure would look like:

```
@certs.each do |cert|
  if cert.attend == "Yes"
    @trained_user_id << cert.user_id #all user ids in certification table
    id = cert.user_id                 
    if u = User.find(id)
      @reseller_users_incerts << u.reseller_id  #all reseller ids from certifications table
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Great, I thought I was way off!